# Bitbucket pipeline deploy ssh (make: ssh command not found)

Tags: ssh, bitbucket

Не могу понять что делаю не так.
Суть такая пушу в мастер pipeline собирает контейнеры по инструкции в makefile. Доходит до этой строки

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${PRODUCTION_HOST} -p ${PRODUCTION_PORT} 'docker-compose pull'
```

и выдаёт, не могу понять что сделать, подскажите

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@xx.xx.xx.xx -p 22 'rm -rf docker-compose.yml .env'
make: ssh: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:87: deploy-production] Error 127
```

Может быть ключи или доступ неправильно настроен, но почему (ssh - command not found)?

Comment: Egypt power! Беспарольный по ssh доступ настроить нужно.